# Apply cardinality estimation problem in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, optimization, cardinality-estimates, cross-apply

Now, I am faced with the problem of the logic of cardinality estimation that is not quite clear for me in a seemingly rather simple situation.
I encountered this situation at my work, therefore, for privacy reasons, I will provide only a general description of the problem below, however, for a more detailed analysis, I simulated this problem in the AdventureWorksDW training base.

There is a query of the following form:

```
SELECT <some columns>
FROM <some dates table>
CROSS APPLY(

    SELECT
        <some p columns>
    FROM <some table> p
    WHERE p.StartDate <= Dates.d
      AND p.EndDate >= Dates.d
) t
```

[image]

As you can see from the execution plan presented above, the cardinality estimator estimated the estimated number of rows in the Index Seek operation at 17,884,200 (corresponding to 2,980,700 per row from the outer part of the NL), which is quite close to the actual number.

Now I will modify the query and add to CROSS APPLY LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT <some columns t>
FROM <some dates table>
CROSS APPLY(

    SELECT
        <some p columns>
    <some columns f>
    FROM <some table> p
    LEFT JOIN <some table> f ON p.key = f.key
        AND f.date = Dates.d
    WHERE p.StartDate <= Dates.d
      AND p.EndDate >= Dates.d
) t
```

This query gives the following plan:

[image]

Seeing the logical form of the query, it is logical to assume that the expected number of rows of the Index Seek operation will remain the same, although I understand that the route for finding the plan is different, however, it would seem that the part highlighted in red has not changed, the same predicates, etc. , but Index Seek's estimate is now 664,506 (corresponding to 110,751 per line from the external part of NL), which is a gross mistake and in the production environment can cause a serious tempdb spill data.

The above queries were executed on an instance of Sql Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (x64).

To get more details and simplify the analysis, I simulated this problem in the AdventureWorksDW2017 database on an instance of SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64), but I execute queries with the 9481 trace flag turned on to simulate a system with cardinality estimator version 70.

Below is a query with left outer join.

```
DECLARE @db DATE = '20130720'
DECLARE @de DATE = '20130802'

;WITH Dates AS(

    SELECT [FullDateAlternateKey] AS d
    FROM [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate]
    WHERE [FullDateAlternateKey] BETWEEN @db AND @de
)
SELECT *
FROM Dates
CROSS APPLY(

    SELECT
        p.[ProductAlternateKey]
       ,f.[OrderQuantity]
    FROM [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimProduct] p
    LEFT JOIN [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] f ON f.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
       AND f.[OrderDate] = Dates.d
    WHERE p.StartDate <= Dates.d
      AND ISNULL(p.EndDate, '99991231') >= Dates.d

) t
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481 /*force legacy CE*/)
```

It is also worth noting that the following index was created on the DimProduct table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Date_Indx] ON [dbo].[DimProduct]
(
    [StartDate] ASC,
    [EndDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE([ProductAlternateKey])
```

The query gives the following query plan: (1)

[image]

As you can see, the part of the query highlighted in red gives an estimate of 59,754 (~ 182 per row).
Now I’ll demonstrate a query plan without a left outer join. (2)

[image]

As you can see the part of the query highlighted in red gives a score of 97 565 (~ 297 per row), the difference is not so great however, the cardinality score for the filter (3) operator is significantly different ~ 244 per row versus ~ 54 in the query with left outer join.

(3) – Filter predicate:

```
isnull([AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimProduct].[EndDate] as [p].[EndDate],'9999-12-31 00:00:00.000')>=[AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate].[FullDateAlternateKey]
```

Trying to plunge deeper, I looked at the trees of physical operators presented above plans.

Below are the most important parts of the trace of undocumented flags 8607 and 8612.

For plan (2):

```
PhyOp_Apply lookup TBL: AdventureWorksDW2017.dbo.DimProduct
…
PhyOp_Range TBL: AdventureWorksDW2017.dbo.DimProduct(alias TBL: p)(6) ASC  Bmk ( QCOL: [p].ProductKey) IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1002  [ Card=296.839 Cost(RowGoal 0,ReW 0,ReB 327.68,Dist 328.68,Total 328.68)= 0.174387 ](Distance = 2)
              ScaOp_Comp x_cmpLe
                 ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [p].StartDate
                 ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate].FullDateAlternateKey
```

For plan (1):

```
PhyOp_Apply (x_jtInner)
…
PhyOp_Range TBL: AdventureWorksDW2017.dbo.DimProduct(alias TBL: p)(6) ASC  Bmk ( QCOL: [p].ProductKey) IsRow: COL: IsBaseRow1002  [ Card=181.8 Cost(RowGoal 0,ReW 0,ReB 327.68,Dist 328.68,Total 328.68)= 0.132795 ](Distance = 2)


                 ScaOp_Comp x_cmpLe

                    ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [p].StartDate

                    ScaOp_Identifier QCOL: [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate].FullDateAlternateKey
```

As you can see, the optimizer selects various implementations of the Apply operator, PhyOp_Apply lookup in (2) and PhyOp_Apply (x_jtInner) in (1), but I still do not understand what I can extract from this.

I can get the same estimate as in plan (1) by rewriting the original query without left outer join as follows:

```
DECLARE @db DATE = '20130720'
DECLARE @de DATE = '20130802'

;WITH Dates AS(

    SELECT [FullDateAlternateKey] AS d
    FROM [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimDate]
    WHERE [FullDateAlternateKey] BETWEEN @db AND @de
)
SELECT *
FROM Dates
CROSS APPLY(

    SELECT TOP(1000000000)
        p.[ProductAlternateKey]
    FROM [AdventureWorksDW2017].[dbo].[DimProduct] p
    WHERE p.StartDate <= Dates.d
      AND ISNULL(p.EndDate, '99991231') >= Dates.d

) t
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481 /*force legacy CE*/)
```

Which gives the following plan: (4)

[image]

As you can see, the estimation of the area highlighted in red coincides with the plan (1) and the PhyOp_Apply (x_jtInner) operator in the tree of physical operators.

Please help me answer the question, is there a way to influence such an estimation of cardinality, possibly by hints or by changing the query form, etc., and help to understand why the optimizer gives such an estimation in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are often several ways to derive a cardinality estimate, with each method giving a different (but equally valid) answer. That is simply the nature of statistics and estimations.

You ask essentially why one method produces an estimate of **296.839** rows, while another gives **181.8** rows.

---

Let's look at a simpler example of the same AdventureWorksDW2017 join as given in the question:

#### Example 1 - Join

```
DECLARE @db date = '20130720';
DECLARE @de date = '20130802';

SELECT DD.FullDateAlternateKey, DP.ProductAlternateKey
FROM dbo.DimDate AS DD
JOIN dbo.DimProduct AS DP
    ON DP.StartDate <= CONVERT(datetime, DD.FullDateAlternateKey)
WHERE
    DD.FullDateAlternateKey BETWEEN @db AND @de
OPTION (FORCE ORDER, USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'));
```

This is a join between:

- `DimDate` (filtered on `FullDateAlternateKey BETWEEN @db AND @de`); and
- `DimProduct`

with the join predicate being:

- `DP.StartDate <= CONVERT(datetime, DD.FullDateAlternateKey)`

One way to compute the **selectivity of the join** is to consider how `FullDateAlternateKey` values will overlap with `StartDate` values using **histogram** information.

The histogram steps of `FullDateAlternateKey` will be scaled for the selectivity of `BETWEEN @db AND @de`, before being compared with `DP.StartDate` to see how they join.

Using the original CE, the join estimation will align the two histograms step by step using linear interpolation before being 'joined'.

Once we have computed the selectivity of the join using this method, it doesn't matter (except for display purposes) whether the join is a hash, merge, nested loops, or apply.

The steps of the histogram-based calculation aren't particularly difficult, but they are too long-winded to show here. So I will cut to the chase and simply show the outcome:

[image]

Notice the estimate of **296.839** rows on the `DimProduct` seek.

This is a consequence of the join cardinality estimate being computed as 97,565.2 rows (using histograms). The filter on `DimDate` passes through 328.68 rows, so the inner side must produce 296.839 rows per iteration on average to make the maths work out.

If a hash or merge join were possible for this query (which it isn't, due to the inequality), the `DimProduct` table would be scanned, producing all of its 606 rows. The result of the join would still be 97,565.2 rows.

This estimate is a consequence of estimating as a join.

#### Example 2 - Apply

We could also estimate this query as an *apply*. A logically-equivalent form written in T-SQL is:

```
DECLARE @db date = '20130720';
DECLARE @de date = '20130802';

SELECT DD.FullDateAlternateKey, DP.ProductAlternateKey
FROM dbo.DimDate AS DD
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT DP.ProductAlternateKey
    FROM dbo.DimProduct AS DP
    WHERE
        DP.StartDate <= CONVERT(datetime, DD.FullDateAlternateKey)
) AS DP
WHERE
    DD.FullDateAlternateKey BETWEEN @db AND @de
OPTION (FORCE ORDER, USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'), QUERYTRACEON 9114);
```

*(trace flag 9114 prevents the optimizer rewriting the apply as a join)*

The estimation approach this time is to assess how many rows will match in `DimProduct` for each row from `DimDate` (per iteration):

[image]

We have 328.68 rows from `DimDate` as before, but now each of those rows is expected to match **181.8** rows in `DimProduct`.

This is simply a **guess** at the selectivity of `StartDate <= FullDateAlternateKey`.

The guess is 30% of the 606 rows in `DimProduct`: 0.3 * 606 = **181.8** rows.

This estimate is a consequence of estimating as an apply.

#### Final notes

Your example introduces an outer join as a way to make the query too complex for the optimizer to transform from apply to join form. Using `TOP` inside the apply is another way to convince the optimizer not to translate an apply to join (even when it could).